# How to call Json data using local variable?

Tags: json, local-variables

I have created a Spinner list of string, which are same as the Json String. As like this:

Spinner list:

```
list.add("AED");list.add("ALL");list.add("AMD");list.add("ANG");list.add("AOA");list.add("ARS");
```

Json Data:

```
{"AED":4.065064,"AFN":86.705252,"ALL":121.591451,"AMD":525.502916,"ANG":1.94743,"AOA":404.690194,"ARS":62.08047}
```

I want to call Json data by selecting a item from my spinner list.

when I pass the string from my list Nothing happend.

```
protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            try {
                final JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(result);
                String currencyDetails= jsonObject.getString("rates");
                Log.i("Value is",currencyDetails);

                firstSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int first, long l) {

                        try {
                            String uniqueValue =jsonObject.getString(list.get(first));


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
```

Could someone tell me, can I do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

There is one mistake, on the line

```
 String uniqueValue = jsonObject.getString(list.get(first));
```

From the given JSON data, It has double value for every key-value pairs. You can see-

```
{"AED":4.065064,"AFN":86.705252,"ALL":121.591451,"AMD":525.502916,"ANG":1.94743,"AOA":404.690194,"ARS":62.08047}
```

So, Just get double value instead of string, like this-

```
String uniqueValue = jsonObject.getDouble(list.get(first));
```

Comment: Thanks, but same error happened.                                                              
 W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for ANG

Comment: Check if jsonObject has this key, like - if (jsonObject.has(list.get(first))){String uniqueValue = jsonObject.getDouble(list.get(first));}